# Swift iOS app - issue with change storyboard segue kind - cant change from modally to show

Tags: ios, swift, segue

As you can see - i selected show but on main storyboard and in app it works like modaly.
What's wrong with it?

[image]

Even if i change to any other option, it works modally!

Edit: If i add button and segue to other view - it works always modally to even if i change this value.

Comment: Because you have no navigation controller!

Answer (score 1):

For appearing with "Back" button in the navigation bar, you need to use Navigation Controller at first. In order to can push inside.

Check the image, Now it will be handled to push inside the stack of the view controllers of the navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean, Change Size from "Inferred" to "Detail" ?

Comment: Im not sure, i rebuilding my first app from beginning because i made to many bad decisions and in my old map i just selected Show and it works fine with navigation and everything - there i had that issue from start

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPKCULKi0-A - in this tutorial it working as show and with back button, how to get this?

Comment: Okay, i found both options. After change in Main.storyboard it looks ok with back button and fullscreen but when i try to run my app it works modally without back button :(

Comment: I can't found any solution for that, that irritating because i can't make any app with that issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer, in order to get your exact point then. Try and let me know.